# do operation on two variables from the file

Tags: variables, ksh

I am a newbee into ksh programming. I have a stuff to do.

I have a file like a.txt

```
    105b  /vol/na5b_vol001/lore_000   hdisk478         fcs0     FCP        512.0g (549782028288)        
    105a  /vol/an5a_vol001/aj_001     hdisk479         fcs0     FCP        512.0g (549782028288)       
    105b  /vol/an5b_vol002/aj_002     hdisk480         fcs0     FCP        512.0g (549782028288)       
    105a  /vol/an5a_vol002/aj_003     hdisk481         fcs0     FCP        512.0g (549782028288)
```

I want to ssh to $1 of the file and do some operation on $2 of the file. Like
`ssh $i lun stat -o $2`

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r server volume line
do
    ssh "$server" "lun stat -o \"$volume\""
done < a.txt
```